# Python: Sum multiple columns in a Data Frame by each unique row entry in another column

Tags: python, dataframe, sum

How do I sum multiple columns (e.g. columns C4, C5 and C6) by using each unique entry in another column (e.g. by column C2).

For example, I would like to create a new dataframe that would collapse column C2 by import and export and show also the sum of C4, C5 and C6 (and preferably drop the other columns C1 and C3).

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDWix.png)

Comment: Please provide a sample code that you tried

Comment: I've simplified the problem because my actual dataset is too large but If xdata is my dataframe, I'v used ydata = xdata.sum(axis=0) to get a sum of every column and then essentially used ydata[C4:] to isolate the grand total but have obviously not retained the ability to sum by specific row entries in columns C1, C2 or C3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups) function

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'Import', 'Argentina', 1, 1, 1],
                   ['B', 'Import', 'Brazil', 2, 2, 2],
                   ['C', 'Export', 'UJ', 3, 3, 3],
                   ['D', 'Export', 'US', 4, 4, 4],
                   ['A', 'Export', 'Canada', 5, 5, 5],
                   ['B', 'Export', 'Russia', 6, 6, 6],
                   ['C', 'Import', 'China', 7, 7, 7],
                   ['D', 'Import', 'India', 8, 8, 8]], 
                  columns=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6'])

results = df.groupby("C2").sum()

print(results)
```

Which will give you

```
        C4  C5  C6
C2                
Export  18  18  18
Import  18  18  18
```

Comment: thanks that is very helpful, exactly what I was missing. Is there a better way to ignore preceding unwanted columns other than creating a new dataframe that is: results[C4:]

Comment: @KSQ pandas tends to work by creating new copies of the dataframe when changes are made, some functions have an `inplace` option to not create a new copy. For example, to drop come columns you could do `df.drop(['C1', 'C2', C3'], axis=1, inplace=True)`, which would return only the last few columns and not create a copy.